# Why a new thread executed without creating a new one?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

Once in a while, there is another thread which starts to execute my code.

```
// the main method:
// ...
   MatchResultsForRules(rules, results);
   ApplyRules(rules);
//...

public void MatchResultsForRules(List<Rule> Rules, List<SearchResult> Results)
{
   foreach (Rule rule in Rules)
   {
      foreach (SearchResult res in Results)
      {
         if (isResultMatchRule(rule, res))
         {
            rule.searchResults.Add(res);
         }
      }
   }
}

public void ApplyRules (List<Rule> Rules)
{
   foreach (Rule rule in Rules)
   {
      foreach(SearchResult res in rule.searchResults)
      {
         ApplyRule(rule, res);
      }
   }
}
```

I know there is another thread because once I saw the issue occurs (calculation mismatches), I printed a detailed log including the thread Id for each action and I saw a mess in the order of actions and of course, two different thread ids.

I fixed the issue by manipulating the search results itself instead of manipulating each rule's search results list (explained beneath).

The fix:

```
public void ApplyRules (List<Rule> rules, List<SearchResult> searchResults)
{
   foreach (Rule rule in rules)
   {
      foreach(SearchResult resFromRule in rule.searchResults)
      {
         SearchResult res = searchResults.First(
            r => r.Id.Equals(resFromRule.Id)
         );
         ApplyRule(rule, res);
      }
   }
}
```

I just want to understand this issue better in order to not repeat this mistake in the future.

Comment: How do you know there is another thread messing up the calculations?

Comment: unfortunatly we don't have enough code to understand what is going on. Can you give code calling ApplyRules for instance?

Comment: Is this a search that is kicked off by keystrokes from a user?

Comment: Could it be that all rule.SearchResults in fact referenced the same list?

Comment: @dedecos - I edited the question and I explained that I added a log which prints the thread Ids.

Comment: @BrunoBelmondo - I added more code, let me know if you want to see anything else.

Comment: @Fildor - you are right, before the fix - I manipulated the search results via the rules search results list (which reference the "original" search results list).

Comment: @MaozHeiferman - You need to provide enough code to replicate your issue. Nothing you have shown explains anything about multiple threads.

Comment: @Enigmativity - this is actually all you need, I don't have anything else to add.
I can't reproduce this issue locally, this issue is being reproduced only if the site gets a lot of requests in parallel.

Comment: @MaozHeiferman - Actually, it is not all we need. You should delete this question as it is unanswerable.

Comment: @Enigmativity - hey, what else can I add here?
I really added all the info I got.

Comment: @MaozHeiferman - But it is insufficient to get an answer. You should probably delete it if you can't give us more. It's really unclear to me why you can't give us more though.

Comment: Could you add the implementation of `ApplyRule(rule, res)` and let us know where and when you instantiate the variables rules and results.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the assumption that `rules` and `results` are shared or singleton instances and that the following code is called in parallel:

```
MatchResultsForRules(rules, results);
ApplyRules(rules);
```

`MatchResultsForRules()` edits your `searchResults` via `rule.searchResults.Add(res)`. Then you might have a short time gap before `ApplyRules()` iterates throuh the results via `foreach(SearchResult res in rule.searchResults)`. During that time gap another thread might be executing `MatchResultsForRules()` and edit `searchResults`. Even more: if one thread attempts to edit `searchResults` at the same time as another iterats through it, you are going to end up with an Exception.

To avoid these kind of error

1. Ask yourself if it is required to store the `searchResults` only to iterate it later. Instead of `rule.searchResults.Add(res);` you could directly call `ApplyRule(rule, res);` I am aware that there might be other reasons or code portions why you might need to store the result.
2. Consider whether you could not use shared instances, but provide every thread with it's own instances.
3. Use the lock keyword to make sure that this portion of code is not executed in parallel. This approach might drastically decrease your runtime performance.

```
lock(yourSharedReadonlyLockObject)
{
   MatchResultsForRules(rules, results);
   ApplyRules(rules);
}
```